# Regex for finding specific text in Jenkins console logs

Tags: python, regex

I am writing Python script for filtering Jenkins console log for a Jenkins job and I want to search for a specific pattern/text with regular expressions. 
Below is the text that I am looking for:

```
somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()
```

This is a part of following paragraph or sentence:

```
Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void 
com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.somename.SomeTest.testSomeName().
The result is not deployed to Platform but we will proceed 
with further tests.......
```

Above such sentences are present in the console log for more than 20 times. I want to find each instance of 
this and get that method name `somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()`. I have attempted this so far `\[([^\]]+)\] not deployed ([^ ]+)` and something
is missing/incorrect as a part of this regular expression

Following is the small snippet of the log and I want to find out `test method name` from each of below shown 
    `Failed to find the annotation....` sentences:

```
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:170)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:92)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.somename.SomeTest.testSomeName(). The result is not deployed to Platform but we will proceed with further tests
21:18:26 somename.client.test.utilities.Platform.PlatformApiException: Platform API returned HTTP 400("Field :case_id is not a valid test case.")
21:18:26    at somename.client.test.utilities.platform.PlatformApiClient.sendRequest(PlatformApiClient.java:197)
21:18:26    at
```

Above is just a small snippet; imagine occurrence of above snippet in the log like more than 20 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can scan the output per-line. Try this regexp

```
.* ([^ ]+\(\)).*not deployed.*
```

Example how this works with your example using Perl (regexp is the same)

```
$ cat example | perl -ne 'print $1 if /([^ ]+\(\)).*not deployed/;'
com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()
```

Comment: Hey Marcin, yes I am able to scan the output per line and using the regexp `.* ([^ ]+\(\)).*not deployed.*`, I got closer to my desired output. I am getting this `com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()` as you have mentioned. Is there a way we can get rid of the initial `com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.` part (which is my original question) and just print `somename.SomeTest.testSomeName()`. This part that I want to remove further is going to be same every time.

Comment: Sure, you can just put that part before the mateched expression,e.g. `/com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.([^ ]+\(\)).*not deployed/`

Answer (score 2):

## Description

```
^.*?(\[Error\]).*?\.((?:[a-z]+\.){2}[a-z]+\(\))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regex will do the following:

- find all the lines with `[error]`
- capture the method name which are the three blobs of text preceding the `()`

## Example

**Live Example**

https://regex101.com/r/kI4cL2/1

**Sample Text**

```
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:170)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:92)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
21:18:19    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.alpha.SomeTest.testSomeName(). The result is not deployed to Platform but we will proceed with further tests
21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.bravo.SomeTest.testSomeName(). The result is not deployed to Platform but we will proceed with further tests
21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.charlie.SomeTest.testSomeName(). The result is not deployed to Platform but we will proceed with further tests
21:18:26 somename.client.test.utilities.Platform.PlatformApiException: Platform API returned HTTP 400("Field :case_id is not a valid test case.")
21:18:26    at somename.client.test.utilities.platform.PlatformApiClient.sendRequest(PlatformApiClient.java:197)
21:18:26    at
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = 21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.alpha.SomeTest.testSomeName()
[0][1] = [ERROR]
[0][2] = alpha.SomeTest.testSomeName()

[1][0] = 21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.bravo.SomeTest.testSomeName()
[1][1] = [ERROR]
[1][2] = bravo.SomeTest.testSomeName()

[2][0] = 21:18:26 2016-05-12 21:18:25.238 [ERROR] (1): Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test public void com.somename.qa.mobile.tests.charlie.SomeTest.testSomeName()
[2][1] = [ERROR]
[2][2] = charlie.SomeTest.testSomeName()
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Error                    'Error'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2}                     end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Comment: What a fantastic writeup!